# Remove previous chapter header from Glossary

Tags: glossaries

I have a setup as follows:

```
\chapter{Conclusion}
blah blah ...

\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary[type=main]

\printbibliography
```

Now, the documentclass I'm using always prints the name of the current chapter at the top of each page. The title in bibliography is correct ('Bibliography'), but the title in the glossaries is 'Conclusion'.

I assume that the `\printglossary` command somehow didn't finish the previous chapter. What can I do to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Try a `\cleardoublepage` before `\printglossary`, but without a real code, this is only guessing

Comment: try `\markboth{}{}` before `\printglossary`

Comment: The chapter mark is set using `\glsglossarymark{title}` and its behaviour depends on the document class and page style.

Answer (score 1):

This fixes it by forcing the heading:

```
\markboth{Acronyms}{Acronyms}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\markboth{Glossary}{Glossary}
\printglossary[type=main]

\printbibliography
```

I would like to thank the user 'touhami' for suggesting this in the comments.